# Log post parameters of api gateway call by user

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to log the post values of some variables. Depending on what every user with a valid API keys requests the price should be calculated.

Let's say I want to save how often the user requests for `?qualitiy=high` and `?quality=low` so I can do something like `billing = high * 1 + low * 0.5`

I connected the api gateway with Cloudwatch to log every request and it logs everything so I would be able to calculate the price with a script running over the entries. But there is no way to define what the logger should save so there is a huge overflow.

Another idea was to put a lambda function before the request is going to the api where I can extract the necessary information from the request and save it to another place. But I don't know where I can place it. I was thinking about writing an own Authorization function and handle it there.

So is the best way to handle such a case to abuse the authorization function to inspect the request and save some information?

Answer (score 2):

An authorizer may be a bad fit for this situation as you will not have access to the full request.

You can simply use the Lambda proxy integration, do your processing, then call your downstream API from within the Lambda. This would not be disimilar to the existing proxy Lambda mentioned in [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-with-vpc-endpoints-via-aws-lambda/).